# RewriteRule For Domain Change

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I'm trying to write a ReriteRule in an **.htaccess** file that will redirect requests to our new domain. This is the rule I'm trying to use.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Domain name fix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !www.university.edu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$        http://www.university.edu/engineering/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

My intention is that any request to this web server that does not contain the domain name www.university.edu will be redirected to the engineering subsite. Everything hosted on this web server must appear as coming from that subsite. This RewriteRule is not working. Am I using the wrong approach? Should I use a Vistual Host or a Server Alias instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in an `.htaccess` file, there's no leading `/` on the path the `RewriteRule` matches.  Change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.university.edu/engineering/$1 [R=301]
```